# Doctrine2 Two repositories on the same entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I don't know how to clearly explain my problem but i'll try :)

I have a project with two modules:

- Admin
- User

I also have two doctrine entities that cause me some troubles:

- Shop
- Products

My problem is that theses entities must be used by the Admin and User module, but with doctrine one Entity = one Repository (as far as i know).

How can i for having an working folders structure with doctrine like that:

```
-db
    -entities
        -Shop.php
        -Product.php
    -repositories
        -admin_ShopRepository.php (work with Shop entity but with an admin user)
        -admin_ProductRepository.php (work with Product entity but with an admin user)
        -user_ShopRepository.php (work with Shop entity but with an simple  user)
        -user_ProductRepository.php (work with Product entity but with an simple  user)
```

In fact,  i would like to be able to do:

```
$adminShopRepo = $adminEntityManager->getRepository('Shop');

$userShopRepo = $userEntityManager->getRepository('Shop');
```

Thanks by advance for your answers and sorry for my bad english ! ^^

Comment: theres no problem with what youre trying to do, you just need a relationship set up between them.  If I have time later Ill give you a proper answer. In the meantime have a read of [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html)

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look right now ! :)

Comment: After days searching for what i need, i think my question isn't really clear, in fact i would like to have have one entity manager because i only have one DB, but i also would like to have two repositories targetting the same entity, is it possible?